# Convert Spark Dataframe to Scala Map of key, list of values

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe of the form:

```
Abc      | apple
Abc      | mango
xyz      | grapes
xyz      | peach
```

I want to convert this dataframe into a scala map of (key, list of values) eg: (Abc->(apple,mango), (xyz -> (grapes,peach)).

My code :

```
concatenatedLogs.collect.map( r => {
  val key = r(0).toString
  val value = r(1).toString
  var currList = testMap.getOrElse(key,List[String]())
  currList = value ::currList
  testMap+=(key -> currList)
 }
)
```

It gives me Java heap space out of memory error. Is there a more efficient and easy way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark is a distributed processing framework, when you are dealing with a lot of data. Spark is processing them on a cluster, when you call the collect function all the data that is read on all the different cores/machines is brought back to the driver. When you are doing this you need to make sure, you have enough memory on your driver.

What you are doing is highly inefficient, because you are collecting the entire dataframe to the driver and then you are doing transformations on it. Using spark, you could do something similar with the code below:

```
  val someDF = Seq(
    ("Abc", "apple"),
    ("Abc", "mango"),
    ("xyz", "grapes"),
    ("xyz", "peach")
  ).toDF(
    "group", "fruit")


  val s = someDF.groupBy(col("group")).
    agg(collect_list("fruit").as("fruits")).as[(String, List[String])].collect.toMap
```

the output of this

```
Map(Abc -> List(apple, mango), xyz -> List(grapes, peach))
```